# Remove Duplicate Yara Rules with PowerShell Regular Expressions

Tags: regex, parsing, powershell

Yara rules are used to detect malware by applying regular expressions to files to look for specific patterns in the binary. I keep all of my yara rules in one text file. As I get new rules, I simply paste them to the end of the text file. I'm trying to right a PowerShell 2.0 script that will parse through my Yara rules and identify and remove any duplicate entries.

Here's the format of a yara rule:

**rule [name] { [contents] }**

Here is an example rule:

```
rule CrowdStrike_CSIT_14004_02 : loader backdoor bouncer  {
meta:
    description = "Deep Panda Compiled ASP.NET <http://ASP.NET> Webshell"
    last_modified = "2014-04-25"
    version = "1.0"
    report = "CSIT-14004"
    in_the_wild = true
    copyright = "CrowdStrike, Inc"
    actor = "DEEP PANDA"
   strings:
    $cookie = "zWiz\x00" wide
    $cp = "es-DN" wide
    $enum_fs1 = "File system: {0}" wide
    $enum_fs2 = "Available: {0} bytes" wide
    $enum_fs3 = "Total space: {0} bytes" wide
    $enum_fs4 = "Total size: {0} bytes" wide
   condition:
    ($cookie and $cp) or all of ($enum*)
}
```

What I ultimately want to do is remove all duplicates based on the rule name. However, I would like to have the option of choosing which rule to remove if they have the same name but also have different contents.

In order to accomplish this, I was planning on creating an associative array with the name of the rule being the key and the content of the rule being the value. I want to parse all rules with regular expressions and add them to the associative array as I go, if the rule(key) is already in the array, then I would like either skip the rule (if the contents are the same) or display both rules and choose which one to keep (if the contents are not the same).

After going through all the rules, the associative array would be written out to a file and all duplicates will be eliminated.

**Update:** It works now. Here is the script:

```
# Display proper usage and exit if no file is given
if ($args.Length -ne 1) { 
    Write-Host "`nUsage: .\yara-dedupe.ps1 [full-path-to-yara-rules]"
    exit    
}

# Display info and warning
Write-Host "`nNOTE: Use full path of rule file`n" 
$y = Read-Host "This script is EXPERIMENTAL and will modify $args. Backing up this file is recommended. If you still want to continue, enter (y)"
# Exit if y is not entered
if ($y -ne 'y') { exit}

# File path is passed on from the command line
$FilePath = $args

# This reads in the entire file as one string for multi-line matching
$File = [io.file]::ReadAllText($FilePath)
# Regular expression to separate the rule from the name
$Pattern = "(?smi)rule(.*?)\{(.*?condition:.*?)\}\r"
# All matching rules parsed according to the regular expression
$ParsedRules = $File | Select-String $Pattern -AllMatches

# A hash table (associative array) to store all rules
$Rules = @{}

# Add each non-duplicated rule to the hash table
$ParsedRules.Matches | Foreach { 

    # Extract rule name
    $Rule = $_.Groups[1].Value.Trim()
    #Extract rule content
    $Content = $_.Groups[2].Value.Trim()

    # Check if rule is already in the hash table
    if ($Rules.ContainsKey($Rule)) {

        Write-Host "Rule Exists: $Rule"

        # If it is, check if the content is identical and skip duplicate if it is
        if ($Rules.$Rule -eq $Content) { Write-Host "Skipping duplicate..." }

        # If it is not, then choose which one to accept
        else {
            # Display current rule content
            Write-Host "`nCurrent Rule Content[1]:"
            $Rules.$Rule
            # Display new rule content
            Write-Host "`nNew Rule Content[2]: $Content`n`n"
            # Ask user which rule content to keep
            $Choice = Read-Host 'Enter 1 to keep existing rule content, 2 to overwrite rule content with new rule content'
            # If choice was 1, continue to next rule
            if ($Choice -eq "1") { Write-Host "`nKeeping original content`n" }
            # Otherwise overwrite the existing rule content with the new rule content
            else { 
                $Rules.Set_Item($Rule,$Content)
                Write-Host "`nRule updated!`n"
            }
         }

    # Add the rule if it is not in the hash table
    } else { 
        $Rules.$Rule = $Content
        Write-Host "Rule Added: $Rule"
    } 
}

# Erase current file
Clear-Content $FilePath

# Output the hash table to file
$Rules.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object { Add-Content $FilePath "rule $($_.Key) {`n $($_.Value) `n}" }
Write-Host "De-duplication complete. New rules located at $FilePath"
```

Comment: So `rule .. { .. }` is the literal of what you search?

Comment: I'd check the docs of Powershell to find out how to index the `$matches` variable. Something like a regular indexing construct or maybe like `$Matches{1}` or something.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this, use MULTILINE and DOTALL modes.
This is tough because `{}` can appear inside the rule, but if you stick to a
group of delimiter constraints, it should work ok.

Capture grp 1 is the name, grp 2 is the rule body, also trims whitespace.

```
 #  (?s)^rule\s+([^{}]+?)\s*\{\s*(.+?)\s*\}$

 (?s)                     # Dot-All modifier (put '(?sm)' here) if your engine supports it ..
                          # otherwise, put them in the flags option of the regex object.  

 ^                        # Open Delimiter = BOL + 'rule' + name + '{'
 rule \s+ 
 ( [^{}]+? )              # (1), Rule name
 \s* 
 \{                       # '{'
 \s* 
 ( .+? )                  # (2), the rule, ungreedy
 \s* 
 \}                       # '}'
 $                        # Close Delimiter = '}' + EOL
```

Output:

```
 **  Grp 1 -  ( pos 5 , len 51 ) 
CrowdStrike_CSIT_14004_02 : loader backdoor bouncer  
 **  Grp 2 -  ( pos 61 , len 552 ) 
meta:
    description = "Deep Panda Compiled ASP.NET <http://ASP.NET> Webshell"
    last_modified = "2014-04-25"
    version = "1.0"
    report = "CSIT-14004"
    in_the_wild = true
    copyright = "CrowdStrike, Inc"
    actor = "DEEP PANDA"
   strings:
    $cookie = "zWiz\x00" wide
    $cp = "es-DN" wide
    $enum_fs1 = "File system: {0}" wide
    $enum_fs2 = "Available: {0} bytes" wide
    $enum_fs3 = "Total space: {0} bytes" wide
    $enum_fs4 = "Total size: {0} bytes" wide
   condition:
    ($cookie and $cp) or all of ($enum*)
```